# How do I initialize a jQuery UI datepicker to a date from the querystring?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Given this markup:

```
// Calendar.html?date=1/2/2003
<script>
  $(function() { 
    $('.inlinedatepicker').datepicker();
  });
</script>
...

<div class="inlinedatepicker" id="calendar"/>
```

This will display an inline datepicker with very little effort (awesome!). How do I preset the datepicker to the date passed in via the query string?

Note that in this case, I don't have an input box--just a calendar attached to a div.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work, though you may run into locale issues (specifically, M/D/Y vs. D/M/Y).

```
var date = location.match(/(?:\?|&)date=(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)(&|$)/)[1];
$('.inlinedatepicker').datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date(date));
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. It seems crazy to me that there's not a jquery  built-in to get a querystring parameter value without using plugins or complicated code.

Comment: I don't doubt there's a plugin for it somewhere, but the jQuery core contains very little aside from DOM manipulation and Ajax.

Comment: this distubs my enddate and format, didnt work for me

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this with

```
$('.inlinedatepicker').datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date(2011,11,01)); // Date equals December 1, 2011.
```

I had to subtract one from the month though to get the right date as it seems that date is starting from zero (0 = January)

Answer (score 2):

in addition to @Ben Blank answer you can use **defaultDate** like this

```
var date = location.match(/(?:\?|&)date=(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)(&|$)/)[1];
$('.inlinedatepicker').datepicker({defaultDate:new Date(date)});
```